# Programatically Moving the Cursor with the Thumb when the ScrollBar.Maximum Property Changes

Tags: c#, cursor, scrollbar

In my application I have a `VScrollBar` control that I use to scroll the contents of a control up and down.  But data is being added to the control in realtime, and as data is added, I adjust the `VScrollBar.LargeChange` and `VScrollBar.Maximum` values.  The thumb moves appropriately when this happens, and since `VScrollBar.Value` isn't changing, the displayed content of my control doesn't change.  This is working perfectly.

However, my problem is that if the user is holding down the mouse button on the thumb while the contents of the control are changing (and thus `VScrollBar.LargeChange` and `VScrollBar.Maximum` are changing) the thumb will move but the cursor stays in the same position; it doesn't move with the mouse.

I would like the mouse to gradually move upwards along with the thumb as new data is added.

How can I move the cursor programatically so that it's position relative to the thumb stays constant?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to not move the thumb if the user is trying to "hold" it?

Comment: @RufusL  Because the contents of the control are changing, i.e. more data is getting added to it, the relative position of the thumb moves in order for the contents of the control to stay fixed.  For example, say there are 100 lines and the value of the scroll bar is 50, so we're seeing data starting about 50 lines down, and the thumb is about in the middle of the scrollbar.  Now, 100 more lines are added, but the value is still 50:  the thumb will be about 1/4 of the way from the top, and the scrollbar still shows data starting about 50 lines down.

Comment: So if the user is holding down the thumb at a value of 50, I don't want the value to change as more data is being added since I want the displayed data to remain fixed.  This works naturally without doing anything special, but a side effect is that as the thumb moves upwards when new data is added the cursor stays fixed and the distance between the thumb and cursor grows.